Dual-booted laptop can't shut down properly causing overheating
This is my first time trying to dual boot Linux so I don't know anything about what I'm doing.
I followed this tutorial on how to dual-boot Windows 11 and Mint.
The problem is that when I try shutdown my laptop through Mint it will fail to shutdown properly and slowly start heating up (the highest I caught it at was 100F on the outside) and draining the battery while running the fans. When I boot up the laptop again it starts me in the GRUB menu, once I start using the laptop the temperature starts going down to regular.
Update 1: After I tried what Yorik's link said to do I get this message when shutting down through Mint:
[Failed] Failed to start casper-md5check.service - casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums.

Broadcast message from [computer name] (wed 2024-09-04 16:33:36 EDT):

The system will power off now!

My Specs:
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0 clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin v: 6.2.0 vt: 7 dm: LightDM v: 1.30.0
    Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Microsoft product: Surface Laptop 5
    v: 124I:00099T:000M:0200000D:0B:04F:1C:04P:01Y:1U:00S:0 serial: <superuser required> Chassis:
    type: 9 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Microsoft model: Surface Laptop 5 serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: Surface_Laptop_5_for_Business_1950:1951 uuid: <superuser required> UEFI: Microsoft
    v: 11.104.143 date: 03/06/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 39.1 Wh (81.0%) condition: 48.3/47.7 Wh (101.2%) power: 5.9 W volts: 8.2
    min: 7.6 model: SMP 1278967001 type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: discharging cycles: 8
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (2-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-1265U bits: 64 type: MST AMCP
    smt: enabled arch: Alder Lake rev: 4 cache: L1: 928 KiB L2: 6.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 984 high: 1266 min/max: 400/4800:3600 cores: 1: 1044 2: 1266 3: 1100 4: 400
    5: 999 6: 1024 7: 997 8: 980 9: 980 10: 970 11: 982 12: 1076 bogomips: 64512
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Microsoft driver: i915 v: kernel
    arch: Gen-12.2 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:46a8 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Microsoft Surface Camera Front driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-9:2 chip-ID: 045e:0990 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2256x1504 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 596x397mm (23.46x15.63") s-diag: 716mm (28.19")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: Sharp LQ135P1JX51 serial: <filter> res: 2256x1504 hz: 60 dpi: 201
    size: 285x190mm (11.22x7.48") diag: 343mm (13.5") modes: 2256x1504
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris device: 1 drv: swrast
    surfaceless: drv: iris x11: drv: iris inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) device-ID: 8086:46a8
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:51c8 class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-41-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse status: active
    2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3
    chip-ID: 8086:51f0 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 1-10:3 chip-ID: 8087:0026 class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.2 lmp-v: 11
    sub-v: 363c hci-v: 11 rev: 363c class-ID: 7c010c
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 21.56 GiB (4.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: N/A size: 476.94 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: HXC75M0Q temp: 36.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 40.95 GiB used: 21.53 GiB (52.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 33.2 MiB (13.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 12 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 1-9:2 info: Microsoft Surface Camera Front type: video driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 4
    rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 500mA chip-ID: 045e:0990 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Device-2: 1-10:3 info: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: bluetooth driver: btusb interfaces: 2
    rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 100mA chip-ID: 8087:0026 class-ID: e001
  Hub-2: 2-0:1 info: super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s lanes: 1 chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
    class-ID: 0900
  Hub-3: 3-0:1 info: hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-4: 4-0:1 info: super-speed hub ports: 3 rev: 3.1 speed: 20 Gb/s lanes: 2 chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
    class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 33.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: pm: dpkg pkgs: 1952
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB available: 31.17 GiB used: 4.47 GiB (14.4%)
  Processes: 339 Power: uptime: 1h 13m states: freeze,mem suspend: s2idle wakeups: 1
    hibernate: disabled Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Client: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 inxi: 3.3.34



Why be concerned? 100°F is barely warm, about body temperature. How long do fans run? Just a few seconds? Shutdown on Linux rarely takes more than 10 seconds (as opposed to Windows, which can be a minute or more while shutting services).

Once the laptop is shut down it just keeps getting hotter, it got to 100F (on the outside) after about an hour but I don't want to leave it shutdown overnight to see how hot it gets.

That does not sound like a shutdown

related? (for mint: suggests splash screen prohibits proper shutdown) https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=368407

As others have noted: Your computer isn't shut down. You should begin analysis, diagnosis, and research into why your computer isn't shutting down, and probably rephrase your question to make it clear you understand that fact.
